# ArcObjects: Equivalent/Similar object to old Avenue ObjectTag from ArcView 3.x?

Tags: arcobjects

I have annotation where a single annotation feature consists of one or more TextElements and RectangleElements grouped together in a GroupElement and then stored in the annotation feature.  To edit the contents of the annotation feature later, it would be nice to be able to know which elements are related to each other.  The elements have natural groupings, but those groups cannot be grouped together and then grouped into the final GroupElement for storage.  Due to a bug, the ESRI optimized map service cannot handle nested groups in annotation.  (See [this posting](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/55103/why-are-annotation-features-containing-both-graphicelement-and-textelement-objec).)  So all elements just have to be thrown in together.  An identifier object, holding, say, a group name string, attached to each element would make identification of elements belonging to each subgroup much easier to identify.  The Avenue ObjectTag object in old ArcView GIS 3.x (I guess it was a property) used to be great for such things.  You could stick a tag on just about any object in the whole model, including dialog controls.  Really handy.  I haven't thought about this -- until recently -- since the old Avenue days, but it has now come to my consciousness again.  I haven't been able to find anything like the old ObjectTag in ArcObjects.  Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try using [IElementProperties.Name](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/IElementProperties_Interface/001200000463000000/) for this purpose?

Comment: @blah238 - No I didn't. Darn.  How did I miss that one?  Duh.  You save me once again.  Thanks.  (Hanging head in shame)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the most direct equivalent in ArcObjects would be [`IElementProperties.CustomProperty`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/CustomProperty_Property/001200000471000000/):

> **CustomProperty** is a place for developers to attach custom objects to
>   an element. Previous versions of the software required that the
>   specified variant be of type `VT_UNKNOWN`, i.e. a reference to an
>   object, but that requirement has since been removed. Now, the
>   CustomProperty can also be a simple type like an integer, double,
>   boolean (`VARIANT_BOOL`) or a string (`BSTR`).
>
> When this property is an object reference, the object must implement a
>   persistence interface, so if you write a custom object it must
>   implement `IPersistStream` or `IPersistVariant`. As an alternative to
>   writing a custom object, you can use a `PropertySet` or `XMLPropertySet`,
>   since they both already implement `IPersistStream`.
>
> **CustomProperty** is never used by the core ArcObjects for its own
>   elements, but the core software will expect to find an `IPersistStream`
>   or `IPersistVariant` interface when the this property is an object
>   reference, and it is part of an element being retrieved from or stored
>   in an .mxd file.

Comment: Thanks again.  This is just what I had in mind ... and more.  I am prototyping in Python/comtypes/ArcObjects at the moment, so the Name populated with a string will do fine for now; however, all of this is going into .NET eventually, and we may want to do something more sophisticated.